# createMapping doesn't work in mongoosastic

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

I'm new at elastic and I'm facing error...I try to follow documentation and some tutorial that I found but on first step I get error that I'm not able to fix :(

This is my code

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const  mongoosastic = require('mongoosastic')


const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, es_indexed: true },
    email: { type: String },
    city: { type: String }
})
userSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {

    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 9200

})
const User = mongoose.model('elastic', userSchema);

User.createMapping(function (err, mapping) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error creating mapping");
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Mapping successfully created");
        console.log(mapping);
    }
});
module.exports = User;
```

And this is photo of the error
[image]